# Searching .csv file and returning all lines with a specific string c++

Tags: c++, csv, class, object

Sorry this is my first post on here. I am very new to c++. I am currently working on a small project which requires reading data from a .csv file, searching for specific words and then writing all the lines that contain the specific word to they're own .csv file. I will be honest and say I am out of my depth when it comes to classes etc which is why I am asking you good people on here if you would have or know of any examples of this type of problem for me to try to understand it.

Thanks for anything at all!
Jay

Comment: You need to give more information on the structure of your csv file and in what column you are searching. Please give more info

Comment: I was planning to search each row rather than column's

Comment: Assume you have CSV with one line consisting of "1,2,3,4,5". Which number, at what position or column do you want to search for?

Comment: Ok, so it is a csv containing row's of details for grocery products, clothing products and household products. The first column details if it is either grocery, clothing or household. The idea is that as the file is populated with more items in each row; the file could be searched for grocery, clothing or household and return only these items as a separate csv file as a report. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Very good, and what are you searching? Column 1? Can you please give more details. We cannot guess here.

Comment: Yes it would be column 1. Sorry I haven't been as specific, trying to understand it all myself.